# Error updating an AngularFire2 object

Tags: angular, typescript, angularfire2

I'm using AngularFire2 to retrieve a Firebase object:

```
// AuthService
public getUserID (): Observable<string> {
    return this.afAuth.authState.map(user => user ? user.uid : null)
}

// AccountService
private profileInfo: FirebaseObjectObservable<any>
constructor (private db: AngularFireDatabase, private authService: AuthService) {
    this.profileInfo = authService.getUserID().flatMap(uid => {
        return db.object(`Users/${uid}`)
    }) as FirebaseObjectObservable<any>
    // have to explicitly cast it or the compiler complains
    // not sure if that's related
}
```

This all seems to work fine, and I can read the correct data from it, but when I try to update it:

```
public changeProfileInfo (name: string) {
    this.profileInfo.update({name: name})
}
```

I get a runtime error when the function executes: `TypeError: this.profileInfo.update is not a function`.  What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this working by manually assigning it inside the map:

```
this.profileInfo = authService.getUserID().flatMap(uid => {
    const profileInfo = db.object(`Users/${uid}`)
    this.profileInfo = profileInfo
    return profileInfo
}) as FirebaseObjectObservable<any>
```

I'm not happy with this solution, it feels really hack-ish, but at least it works.

**Update**: after further testing, it turns out that this throws an error if you log out and back in, since it loses its reference to the uid.  My best attempt at a workaround is even uglier:

```
this.profileInfo = authService.getUserID().flatMap(uid => {
    const profileInfo = db.object(`Users/${uid}`)
    this.profileInfo.$ref = profileInfo.$ref
    this.profileInfo.update = profileInfo.update
    return profileInfo
}) as FirebaseObjectObservable<any>
```

(and if you want to use any other methods, you'll need to add them individually as well)